# Using Weka generated Decision Tree in Python

Tags: python, weka, decision-tree

I generated a Decision Tree using Weka-GUI and am trying to use the generated Decision Tree in my Python code.

Is there an option in Python to load the DT model and use it or would I have to train the Decision Tree in Python itself using a weka wrapper?

Comment: Did you try looking that way: [python-weka-wrapper3](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3) or [sklearn-weka-plugin](https://github.com/fracpete/sklearn-weka-plugin)?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same version of Weka in GUI and Python wrapper, you can use the same model.

Here are some details:

- Weka Primer - (look at model loading): https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/primer/
- Weka and Python: https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/faqs/can_i_use_weka_from_python/

Also consider some alternatives:

- You can convert some classifiers to Java source code: https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/generating_source_code_from_weka_classes/
- If your model is simple and don't change you can convert the tree to if else statements